# MsDepSvc.exe send files/sensitive information over port 80?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, msdeploy

I'm reading up on WebDeploy, but I'm a bit confused about the differences between the service that runs on port 80 (Remote Agent Service) and port 8172 (IIS Deployment handler?).

As far as I can tell, the remote agent service allows servers to deploy changes to each other (for ex: sync command via msdeploy.exe)...however, it seems like running over port 80 (default http port) is a big risk to me.

Am I wrong in thinking that files/sensitive information would be travelling unencrypted over port 80?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're neither right nor wrong, it depends on the situation/setup/infrastructure.

Anyways, [you can set up the Remote Agent Service with SSL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569093(v=ws.10).aspx):

Uninstall Web Deploy, and install it from a command line with:

```
msiexec /i <msi_filename> /passive ADDLOCAL=ALL LISTENURL=https://+:443/MsDeployAgentService/
```

where `<msi_filename>` is the filename of the Web Deploy installer

Then bind a certificate to the endpoint, using [`netsh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx):

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

where `certhash` is the thumbprint of the certificate and `appid` is any valid GUID

Comment: Thanks! I was spooked when I saw it defaulted to 80 and there wasn't anywhere in the wizard to change it.